# expected indented block error in AWS development kit code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, indentation

I am new to python and I understand this question has been asked numerous times, I cant seem to solve this issue however. I am trying to run a block of code I have copied and pasted from the amazon-rekognition-developer kit (this block of code https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-rekognition-developer-guide/blob/master/code_examples/python_examples/image/python-detect-faces.py ) also shown below ...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    photo='input.jpg'
    bucket='bucket'
    client=boto3.client('rekognition')

    response = client.detect_faces(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}},Attributes=['ALL'])

    print('Detected faces for ' + photo)    
    for faceDetail in response['FaceDetails']:
        print('The detected face is between ' + str(faceDetail['AgeRange']['Low']) 
              + ' and ' + str(faceDetail['AgeRange']['High']) + ' years old')
        print('Here are the other attributes:')
        print(json.dumps(faceDetail, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

I keep getting this error

```
In [197]: if __name__ == "__main__":    
  Input In [197]
    if __name__ == "__main__":
                                  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I have double checked my indentation and have tried every variation of tabbing or spacing (always 4 spaces) there is. I have also tried removing empty lines, and retyping the code myself. I dont understand what I am doing wrong, this is literally code copy and pasted from the development kit.

Comment: If that is on line 197 then I would guess the error is actually earlier (in code we cannot see).

Comment: 197 refers to the 197th command I have issued in the console. the block of code is the complete totality of the script I am trying to run.

Comment: Most likely, you simply cannot directly copy and paste an entire block into this "console", whatever it is (you didn't explain). You need to use some console-specific technique so that it knows that the whole thing is a single piece of code. The error implies that it's trying to understand the first line of the code by itself, without looking at anything else that was pasted, and failing because it doesn't see any code inside the `if`.